# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

How can I fix it? Here's my code:

views:

```
this.find('.deleteButton').unbind('click').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $this.data('url'),
        method: 'DELETE',
        success: function () {
            location.reload();
        }
```

routes:

```
Route::delete('/users/delete/{entity}', [
    'as' => 'users.delete',
    'middleware' => ['permission:delete-recruiters'],
    'uses' => 'UsersController@delete'
]);
```

controllers:

```
public function delete(User $entity)
{
    $entity->delete();
}
```

Comment: It could be because of your CORS settings. You have to add/edit CORS settings. Try googling on it to find out more about what CORS is

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow! I've edited your post so that it contains an actual question and reduced unnecessary indentation, however there's still some things to improve so that it's easier for others to help you. First, the views code looks uncomplete, please fix this. Second, to provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I recommend to omit view and show us the request instead (use dev tools for that). Finally, please clarify where the error is shown.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/ Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Http status 405  is METHOD NOT ALLOWED, which might mean route you are trying to make request to is wrong. Check your $this.data('url'), most likely you are hitting different route.